# How displaying two value for series [for example: "395 — (27%)"]?

Tags: highcharts

How I can realize displaying two values for series: one - is absolute value and other in percent:

||||||||||||||||  200 — (30%)

||||||||  100 — (15%)

|||||||||||||||||||||||||  300 — (45%)

Im use a m_chart plugin for WordPress.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide more info on how your data structure looks like, what kind of series it is etc. Also, the demo will be nice. For now, I can only guess that it could be achieved by using the `dataLabel.formatter` callback.

Comment: Please provide JSfiddle Demo.